# Plotting a route from a list of Points without access to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, route

On ArcMap 10.5.1 with a basic license. I have several excel files I joined with a municipal address layer to create a map to visualize the area for workers.

I am now trying to figure out how best to create a "recommended" route between these points without having any access to the tools I imagine I should be using for this. I cannot access any of the online portions of ArcMap's routing capabilities.

Within the map I'm using I have one way streets labelled, and am using a municipal parcel for the street visualization. Would there be a workflow to get this done given my limitations?

Comment: To route points in ArcGIS Desktop, you'd need to use Network Analyst extension. If you have a streets polyline feature class, you'd be able to build a network dataset and then use the Route solver for this. If you do not have Network Analyst extension, then you could try to search for some online routing website that would let you do the work. I know that Google Cloud Mapping platform (https://enterprise.google.com/maps/pricing/#compare-editions) provides some way to do routing to connect multiple points into a single routing, worth exploring.

Comment: Otherwise, you would need to use some other GIS tools or programming interfaces that would let you solve this, but then you should be willing to install and learn some other GIS application or a programming language.